# C# - variable not setting from another class

Tags: c#, variables, console-application

I have a variable that I'm trying to set with `Class1.SetVariable(variable);` but it won't return the variable I set it to. The variable will equal 0 in the other function in `Class2`, not the 50 that I want. Any ideas? Code:

Updated:

```
class Class1 {
    public int rndk = 0;

    public int Rndk {
        get { return this.rndk; }
        set { this.rndk = value; }
    }
}

class Class2 {
    public Class1 instance = new Class1();

    public Class2() {
        Load();
        Check();
    }

    public void Load() {
        instance.Rndk = 50;
        Console.WriteLine(instance.Rndk);
        // returns 50
    }

    public void Check() {
        Console.WriteLine(instance.Rndk);
        // returns 0
    }
}
```

That's pretty much the code.

Comment: Post the actual complete working example of the problem.

Comment: Please show your real code.

Comment: What is `Class1` in your example? Where is it coming from? Your question makes strictly no sense under its current form.

Comment: And why are you using a keyword as an identifier?

Comment: @LewsTherin Contextual keywords!

Comment: @asawyer Huh? :O I have to google that :P

Comment: @LewsTherin I think you were referring to `(int var)` no?

Comment: `var` was introduced in c# 3.0, so to maintable back compat it only gains the inferred type meaning in certain contexts. `yield` does the same.  That said, it is still a bad idea to use it like this.

Comment: @ReedCopsey There's a whole bunch! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/the35c6y.aspx Edit - Oh. Woops. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, in C#, it's typically better to make this a *Property* instead of a field with a "set method":

```
private int variable = 0;
public int Variable 
{ 
   get { return this.variable; }
   set { this.variable = value; }
}
```

This is essentially two methods, but wrapped in much nicer syntax.

As for the actual issue, I suspect the problem is that your methods aren't working on the same instance of the `Class1` class.  Make sure you're using the same instance in your `Class1` variable, and not creating a new instance each method call.  (Your existing code doesn't demonstrate the actual problem.)

For example, with the above change, this will work:

```
public class Class2
{
    private Class1 instance1 = new Class1();

    public Class2()
    { 
        instance1.Variable = 50;
    }

    public void Print()
    {
         // Using the same instance - will print 50
        Console.WriteLine("Instance value is {0}", instance1.Variable);
    }
```

Comment: It does not work, I get the value in 1 function, but in the other function it returns 0.

Comment: @user1522370 You need to edit your question to show your complete code.  The above code will work, exactly as I wrote it.

Comment: @user1522370 What compiler are you using?  Your current code, if you create an instance of Class2, prints 50 two times.

Comment: I'm using the Visual Studio 2012 Express compiler for C#.

Comment: Weird, I took the code out of my project, and added it to a new project and it works fine. Edit: I fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want `Class1` to be "global", it must be static:

`public static class Class1`

Comment: How do I use a static class in a normal class?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking

Comment: If I turn Class1 into a static class, I get a lot of errors. E.g. 'Class1': static types cannot be used as type arguments

Comment: A static class can only be used as a static class - you would get that error if you try to instantiate it as a regular class (i.e. `new Class1()`). If you only want to use it statically, all you need is `Class1.variable`